# UWP error while building

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, build-error, .net-core

I try to build my UWP app and it gives strange error, I am attacking a screenshot of the error please help!!! and I have VS 2015 enterprise with all the latest SDKs installed. I t seems to be a problem with .NetCore but how can I fix it ?

[image]

Comment: I remember I had similar issue, and ended up reinstalling VS2015 enterprise.

Comment: after reinstalling it was working fine ?